# How to solve unknown expected error in iphone app

Tags: objective-c

I am assigning a value to var with calculations but it shows syntax error i have seen all the brackets still it gives error here is my code .

> appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_With_Guarantee=((appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_No_Guarantee
>   - 5000) / appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_No_Guarantee) *
>   ((appDelegate.Cost_Treatment_SevereEI *
>   appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_SevereEI_Annually) +
>   (appDelegate.Cost_Treatment_ModerateEI *
>   appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_ModerateEI_Annually) +
>   (appDelegate.Cost_Treatment_MildEI *
>   appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_MildEI_Annually)))) *
>   appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Horses_Per_Premise;

Comment: what is dataType of this delegare's variable Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_With_Guarantee

Comment: data type is float i think it is brackets as i think

Comment: There are no brackets in that code. Lots of parentheses, but no brackets.

Comment: Simply count the number of left and number of right. The counts must be even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Your code:-

```
    float Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_With_Guarantee;
    float Cost_Treatment_SevereEI;
    float Same_Vaccination_SevereEI_Annually;
    float Cost_Treatment_MildEI;
    float Same_Vaccination_MildEI_Annually;
    float Same_Vaccination_Horses_Per_Premise;
    float Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_No_Guarantee;
    float Cost_Treatment_ModerateEI;
    float Same_Vaccination_ModerateEI_Annually;

Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_With_Guarantee=(((Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_No_Guarantee - 5000) / Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_No_Guarantee) * (((Cost_Treatment_SevereEI * Same_Vaccination_SevereEI_Annually) + (Cost_Treatment_ModerateEI * Same_Vaccination_ModerateEI_Annually) + (Cost_Treatment_MildEI * Same_Vaccination_MildEI_Annually)) * Same_Vaccination_Horses_Per_Premise));
```

and you can also put Method like:-

```
Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_With_Guarantee=((Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_No_Guarantee - 5000) / Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_No_Guarantee) * ((Cost_Treatment_SevereEI * Same_Vaccination_SevereEI_Annually) + (Cost_Treatment_ModerateEI * Same_Vaccination_ModerateEI_Annually) + (Cost_Treatment_MildEI * Same_Vaccination_MildEI_Annually)) * Same_Vaccination_Horses_Per_Premise;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using exactly same

```
    appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_With_Guarantee=((appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_No_Guarantee - 5000) / appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_No_Guarantee) * ((appDelegate.Cost_Treatment_SevereEI * appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_SevereEI_Annually) + (appDelegate.Cost_Treatment_ModerateEI * appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_ModerateEI_Annually) + (appDelegate.Cost_Treatment_MildEI * appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_MildEI_Annually)))) * appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Horses_Per_Premise;
```

then you have 2 braces extra

try

```
    appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_With_Guarantee=((appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_No_Guarantee - 5000) / appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_No_Guarantee) * ((appDelegate.Cost_Treatment_SevereEI * appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_SevereEI_Annually) + (appDelegate.Cost_Treatment_ModerateEI * appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_ModerateEI_Annually) + (appDelegate.Cost_Treatment_MildEI * appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_MildEI_Annually)) * appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Horses_Per_Premise;
```

Answer (score 0):

appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_With_Guarantee=((appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_No_Guarantee - 5000) / appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Cost_Treatment_Annually_No_Guarantee) * ((appDelegate.Cost_Treatment_SevereEI * appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_SevereEI_Annually) + (appDelegate.Cost_Treatment_ModerateEI * appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_ModerateEI_Annually) + (appDelegate.Cost_Treatment_MildEI * appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_MildEI_Annually)) * appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_Horses_Per_Premise;

This will work. You were using too many brackets.